# Closing one single PPT Presentation via VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I would like to close a PPT via VBA in Excel. The problem is with the Code "PP.Close". (last line of code)

1. It also closes other open PPT Presentations not only the one I "target"
2. Sometimes it closes the Presentation AND the application, sometimes just the Presentation, which in my opinion is strange.

Does somebody know how I can solve those issues?

Kind regards and thank you in advance

```
Sub Saveas_PPT()
Dim PP As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim Sl As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim sh As Variant
Dim company As String
'Dim ws_company As Worksheet
Set Dropdown.ws_company = Tabelle2
company = Dropdown.ws_company.Range("C2").Value

Dim strPOTX As String
Dim strPfad As String
Dim pptApp As Object

strPfad = "C:\Users\Michael\" 'Ordner der Vorlage
 strPOTX = "Test.pptx" 'Hier theoretisch auch 
 filepicker möglich

 Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

 Dim pptVorlage As String
 pptVorlage = strPfad & strPOTX


 Set PP = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptVorlage)



 pptApp.ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks 


'  Dim x As Integer
'  For Each prs In PP.Application.Presentations
'
'  x = x + 1
'  

'If x > 1 Then
''pptApp.ActivePresentation.Close ' Hier auch
'  'PP.Close 'Problem: Hier wird alles geschlossen
'  Exit Sub
'End If
'  Next prs

 'pp.Application.Quit 'vorher FUnktion die schaut ob mehr als eine PPT offen sind. Wenn nur eine dann quit, sonst nur diese hier schließen
 pp.Close
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the [AppActivate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/appactivate-statement) function.

It requires the title of the window.
I'm not sure it will work but at least the correct presentation will be active.

```
AppActivate("the PowerPoint title")
```

Replace `the PowerPoint title` with what the Windows title is.

You could, if that too fails, perhaps use sendkeys after it to ALT + F4 to close the active window, which should be the presentation you want.

Comment: Your approach worked. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. One question: What does the fact that this idea worked mean for my code? I understand that this function activated the PPT I wanted to close, but why do I even have to activate it first?

Comment: @Underhook32 that is how VBA works sometimes. Activating a sheet or an app can sometimes be the way to solve a problem. Do you mind accepting the answer since it worked for you?